# Adding a colorbutton in tinymce dialog with current api

Tags: functions, shortcode, tinymce, plugin-tinymce, color-picker

I'm trying to add a colorbutton in a tinymce dialog box, which i was able to do with the help of using this stackoverflow question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23511566/adding-a-colorbutton-in-tinymce-dialog-with-api-4-x-doesnt-work

The problem is I need it to take the hex value thats selected and inject it into the shortcode. Here is a fiddle i made http://fiddle.tinymce.com/sZeaab it will add the shortcode like this: `[shortcode color='']` but its missing the hex value. I need the shortcode to look like this: 
`[shortcode color='#ffffff']` Also it changes the text color, which isn't what i want either, I am assuming its because of how I have this setup. Is what I'm doing the proper way to do this? Should this script be scrapped and re-wrote? I'm new to wordpress development, so any guidance would be appreciated, since I really don't know what I'm doing when it comes to TinyMCE. Let me know if you need further explanation.